# PWM Three Phases with PIC

Tags: microcontroller, pic, pwm, timer

I am trying to program a PIC18F4550 to control a 3 Phase BLDC motor.

I have doubts about how to make the program, since I have seen many examples that what they do is use the TIMER to generate the 3 shifted PWM signals.

And I don't know why the PWM module that this PIC has is not used to do this process.

Is it not possible to generate 3 shifted signals with the PIC18F4550?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "outdated"? Maybe you mean 
updated"? That would make a bit more sense but still not really make sense. Whatever you mean really mean, I'm pretty sure you are using the wrong word.

Comment: The OP is from Spain. I think 'outdated' is used as a translation for 'defasado' ('shifted').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PWM module in the PIC18 that produces 3-phase PWM is not called a Timer. It is called the Enhanced Capture/Compare PWM module (EECP). It is not a timer, but uses the one of the other timers.

There seems to be conflicting info about when the ECCP's features (even if the ECCP itself might not be) are present on 28-pin devices:

[image]
[image]